# PHP regex case-insensitive on cyrillic charset

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, case-insensitive, cyrillic

I am using `preg_replace` and `preg_match` with PHP, working in this charset: Cyrillic Windows 1251.
I am trying to match a word using the case-insensitive modifier.

I made these tests :

```
$pattern = '/myCyrillicWord1|myCyrillicWord2/i';
$subject = 'Am I able to find MYCyrILlicWord1?';
$res = preg_replace($pattern, 'matched', $subject);
```

**On UTF-8** :

With the utf-8 modifier in the pattern :

```
$pattern = '/myCyrillicWord1|myCyrillicWord2/iu';
$output = 'Am I able to find matched or not';
```

Without :

```
$pattern = '/myCyrillicWord1|myCyrillicWord2/i';
$output = 'Am I able to find MYCyrILlicWord1 or not';
```

**On Windows 1251** :

```
$pattern = '/myCyrillicWord1|myCyrillicWord2/i';
$output = 'Am I able to find MYCyrILlicWord1 or not';
```

The regex is functionnal on utf-8 but not on Windows 1251.
Please notice that I had tested with cyrillics characters like 'х' and 'Х' (which look like latin letters 'x' and 'X').

My question is to know if that behavior is normal ?

How can I match my cyrillics words in Windows 1251 charset with the case-insensitive modifier ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think PCRE supports charsets, so your options are basically

- convert everything to utf8, process and then convert back, or
- use manually crafted regexes for case-insensitivity, like `/[Дд][Ыы][Кк]/` to match `Дык`, `дыК` etc

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. So, you're right as these two variants looks like the answer.

Comment: Ok many thanks for answer. I choose the second variants because it's too heavy to convert the whole page to utf-8 and convert back to its original encoding. It's ok for the moment as I have about ten words to check. I would feel disapointed if I have hundreds word to check and in that case this solution won't suit.